# Handling `'createWebDependency' is not an exported object from 'namespace:shiny'` error in Leaflet Shiny

Tags: leaflet, shiny

When I try using leaflet with shiny I get the error

`Error : 'createWebDependency' is not an exported object from 'namespace:shiny'`

A search online for this error doesn't give me any hits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [THIS thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/763DDYXiZew) you might need to update your shiny version.
If that doesn't help, could you add your output from "sessionInfo()" ?

Comment: thanks, I updated shiny, R and R studio and this seemed to resolve the issue.

Comment: you're welcome - if the issue is resolved it would be nice if you close it by accepting the answer. (by clicking the tick/check mark on the left of an answer)